# Creating public url with hashed slug parameter

Tags: laravel, php-7.2

I would like to have a page that can be reached by public but depending on the parameters on the URL, the access should be verified.
My goals is to prevent people to see the content by increasing the id.
Let me make it clear with an example.

compname.url.com/orderid/23424/{someHashedKey}

So orderid = 23424 is my DB primary key, compname is the unique name of order's company.

My plan is to create a hashed key with orderid and compname with some kind of salted hash.

So that when someone reaches to the page, I will create a hash(md5) from orderid,compname, and a salted hash and match with 'SomehashedKey'

Is this the best way or how should I do this?

Answer (score 0):

How you create the hash is your choice. Youtube for example uses a short alphanumeric code, which isn't a hash (I think). You can just generate a random unique value and save it in a second column and use this value in your urls.